# Spring Boot Autoimport import.sql file - Getting a "Column Not found" Error

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

So I have a table in postgresql and I want to fill it with some values on application start. Here is the Entity (in Kotlin):

```
@Entity
class CalculationType(

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        var id: Long = 0,
        var guid: String = "",
        var title: String = "",
        var modified: Date,
        var creation: Date
)
```

my `import.sql`file is located under `..\.\resources`. it looks like this:

```
insert into calculation_type (guid, title, modified, creation) VALUES ("test", "title", "2013-12-12", "2013-12-12");
```

I am getting an error in German, traslated it says `Column »test« does not exist.`

Thats quite strange because `test` is in my values, not in my column definitions.

Does anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character constants need single quotes

```
insert into calculation_type (guid, title, modified, creation) VALUES ('test", 'title', '2013-12-12', '2013-12-12');
```